# Going from simulations to physical setup

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am soon going to move from simulation to working on a physical robot. Up until now I have only worked in simulations with Gazebo, and all my nodes and files are working fine in the simulations. I'm wondering what changes will have to be made to the files when I use a physical turtlebot.

When I simulate I have a lot of terminals open, I run my launch file which sets up the world and robots in Gazebo on one terminal, and then have one terminal for each of the nodes.

From what I understand, when you use a physical setup you have a remote PC that runs the roscore, and then you launch the turtlebot3_bringup launch file on the actual turtlebot. (https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3/blob/master/turtlebot3_bringup/launch/turtlebot3_robot.launch).

What is done after this? Do I run the nodes on the remote pc or on the turtlebot? Would my nodes work on the physical setup if they worked in the simulations?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/391558/going-from-simulations-to-physical-setup/) by [Azro](https://answers.ros.org/users/90268/azro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-11-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @Azro:

ROBOTIS has very good documentation on Turtlebot3: https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/quick-start/ it walks you step by step on what to do on your physical robot and what to do from your remote PC.

For example how to set your network configuration which will be one critical step.
[image: image description]

Once you setup your remote PC and Turtlebot, then you will proceed on launching nodes as per simulation to control the robot accordingly. Start with teleoperation, making sure driving is working before you try more advanced nodes like autonomous navigation.

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0